# Find integers $k$ and $l$ such that $\gcd(-5775,-651)$ can be expressed in the form $ka + bl$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

As the title suggests, I have to find the following:

> $k$ and $l$ such that $\gcd(-5775,-651)$ can be expressed in the form $ka + bl$

Now, the main issue, I have is figuring out how the negatives play into the scenario. I did Euclid's algorithm in reverse and found that I get $71(651) - 8(5775)$. This would mean that $k = -8$ and $l = 71$ but the answers are $k = 8$ and $l = -71$. So the question is:

> How do negatives factor in when finding $k$ and $l$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Any number at all can be expressed in the form $ka+bl$ - are you intending that $a=-5775, b=-651$?

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Yes, $a = -5775$ and $b = -651$.

Comment: Well then you clearly have the right answer... $lb + ka = (-71)(-651) + (8)(-5775) = 71(651) - 8(5775)$...

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$71(651)-8(5775)=-71(-651)+8(-5775)$$

Comment: Ahhh! So, if we have negative attached to $b$ then we have to "remove" it and for $a$, it has to resemble our original $a$ right? In other words, $a$ and $b$ in $ka + lb$ must be the same $a,b$ we see in $\gcd{(a,b)}$ right?

Comment: @gekkostate If you want $a=-5775, b= -651$ you have to use $(-5775)k+(-651)l$ rather than $(5775)k+(651)l$